# delete all string after character sqlite column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i have sqlite table cars that contains some cars data and a urls from different websites in **"source"** column
what i want to do is clean the urls in **"SOURCE"** column that are for **"example1"** from :
https://www.example1.com/car-details/202205316358623?some_text_here&here
to :
https://www.example1.com/car-details/202205316358623
but only for "example1" site
thank you

Comment: your links have no linked pages @oussama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sqlite you're fairly limited, best I can come up with is something like this:

If `?` is in SOURCE, then take SOURCE from its starting character to where `?` is located. Otherwise, just return SOURCE.

```
substr(SOURCE, 1, iff(instr(SOURCE, '?') > 0, instr(SOURCE, '?'), NULL))
```

You might have to replace the second `instr(SOURCE, '?')` with `instr(SOURCE, '?') - 1`.